# Java set/get all component's text in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, components

I'm trying to access all component's text in a JFrame, but with the method I found I cant do it.

```
    for(Component c : this.getComponents()) {
        c.setText(TRNASLATE(c.getText()));
        // does not work: no set and getText methods
    }
```

Is there any way to get or set a component's text?

Before you ask: i'm trying to translate elements on a JFrame without listing its components manually and setting their texts (it would take a long time to list them one-by-one)

Sorry for my english.

Comment: I think you can use [**`instanceof`**](https://www.javatpoint.com/downcasting-with-instanceof-operator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `instanceof` to check if the component is a certain type, the cast that type to it. Most components have a getText() method.

Example:

```
for(Component c : this.getComponents()) {
       if(c instanceof JLabel){
           JLabel label = (JLabel) c;
           String text = label.getText();
       }
}
```

Repeat `instanceof` with as many Component types as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for any object of Java Swing

```
public static void setSwingObjectText(Object object, String text) {
    if (object instanceof javax.swing.AbstractButton)
        ((javax.swing.AbstractButton)object).setText(text);
    else if (object instanceof javax.swing.JEditorPane)
        ((javax.swing.JEditorPane)object).setText(text);
    else if (object instanceof javax.swing.JLabel)
        ((javax.swing.JLabel)object).setText(text);
    else if (object instanceof javax.swing.text.JTextComponent)
        ((javax.swing.text.JTextComponent)object).setText(text);
    else if (object instanceof java.awt.Frame)
        ((java.awt.Frame)object).setTitle(text);
    else if (object instanceof java.awt.Dialog)
        ((java.awt.Dialog)object).setTitle(text);
    else if (object instanceof javax.swing.JInternalFrame)
        ((javax.swing.JInternalFrame)object).setTitle(text);
    else if (object instanceof javax.swing.border.TitledBorder)
        ((javax.swing.border.TitledBorder)object).setTitle(text);
}
public static String getSwingObjectText(Object object) {
    if (object instanceof javax.swing.AbstractButton)
        return ((javax.swing.AbstractButton)object).getText();
    else if (object instanceof javax.swing.JEditorPane)
        return ((javax.swing.JEditorPane)object).getText();
    else if (object instanceof javax.swing.JLabel)
        return ((javax.swing.JLabel)object).getText();
    else if (object instanceof javax.swing.text.JTextComponent)
        return ((javax.swing.text.JTextComponent)object).getText();
    else if (object instanceof java.awt.Frame)
        return ((java.awt.Frame)object).getTitle();
    else if (object instanceof java.awt.Dialog)
        return ((java.awt.Dialog)object).getTitle();
    else if (object instanceof javax.swing.JInternalFrame)
        return ((javax.swing.JInternalFrame)object).getTitle();
    else if (object instanceof javax.swing.border.TitledBorder)
        return ((javax.swing.border.TitledBorder)object).getTitle();
    else
        return null; //no match
}
```